# Documentation for developing a personal Cardano project

Tags: documentation, build, create-new-project

I am looking to build a personal project related to Cardano. Are there any documents on libraries or APIs to implement functionalities such as checking balance, transferring funds, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at https://docs.cardano.org/introduction/ for some general information about Cardano.

For APIs and tools, https://developers.cardano.org/tools has a big collection of useful projects that you can use. There is also a getting started section that can be useful: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/

Checking balance and submitting transactions can be easily achieved using an API like [Koios](https://koios.rest/) or [Blockfrost](https://blockfrost.io/) if you don't want to run your own infrastructure.

If you use JavaScript, [Mesh](https://meshjs.dev/) is a great library to start building a project on Cardano. Otherwise just have a look at the [tools section of the developer portal](https://developers.cardano.org/tools) to find libraries for the programming language you'd like to use.

Comment: Does Cardano have a testnet similar to Ethereum or Binance Smart Chain?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple, you can find more information about testnets here: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/testnets-and-devnets

Answer (score 0):

The [cardano-db-sync](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync) project follows the chain a inserts on and off chain data into a PostgreSQL database from where it queries using SQL.